# Refactor code using mock and stubb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-mocks

I am a newbie in rails and i am now trying to test my controller code using stubbs and mocks. I tried using mock on the code but i couldnt do it properly . Please help me out with the correct code which is refactored.Please help me out with the explanation for the code that u write .

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ArticlesController, type: :controller do
  let(:article) { create :article}
  let(:art_params) { attributes_for(:article) }
  let(:dbl) {double(:articles)}
  describe 'GET index' do
    it 'assigns @articles' do
      get :index
      allow(dbl).to receive(:articles).and_return article
      expect(dbl.articles).to eql(article)
      #expect_any_instance_of(Article).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
    end

    it 'renders the index template' do
      get :index
      allow(dbl).to receive(:articles)
      expect(response).to render_template('index')
    end
  end

  describe 'GET :new' do
    it 'render new template' do
      get :new
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end
  end

  describe 'POST/create' do
    it 'created a new article ' do
    expect { post :create, article: art_params }.to change(Article, :count).by(1)
    end
  end

  describe 'POST/create not' do
    it 'did not create a new user' do
     # expect(art_params).to receive(attributes_for :article).with(content:)
      art_params = { article: attributes_for(:article, content: nil) }
      post :create, art_params
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end
  end

  describe 'GET/edit' do
    it 'displays the edit template' do
      get :edit, id: article.id
      expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
    end
  end

  describe 'POST/update' do
    it 'displays the update template' do
      post :update, id: article.id, article: attributes_for(:article)
      expect(response).to redirect_to(article_path(article.id))
    end
  end

  describe 'POST/DELETE' do
    it 'destroys the article template' do
      dbl = double()
      article = create :article
      expect { delete :destroy, id: article.id }.to change(Article, :count).by(-1)

    end
  end
en
```

d

Comment: In my opinion mocks and stubs should not be used in controller code that much. Because controller actions are supposed to be small, compact and easy to use. Stubs are used more in unit tests, to, for example, get rid of callbacks in tests or stub some long method or a third party request.

Comment: True, but it could come in handy in some cases. For instance, you could mock a call to an `ActiveRecord#save` for instance if you wanted your tests to go faster and not hit the database every time.

Answer (score 2):

Mocking and stubbing is fairly advanced testing concept to get it really right. Without real understanding it is easy to create fragile tests that break every time when the tested code is changed. Or tests that will always pass.

For example, the following code can't ever fail. You create a test double (`dbl`), then you stub a method (`#articles`) on that double and specify that this method call will return the instance `article`. In the expectation you invoke the `#articles` method on the test double, which has to pass, since you just defined that behaviour on the test double.

```
let(:article) { create :article }
let(:dbl) { double(:articles) } # the test double

it 'assigns @articles' do
  get :index
  allow(dbl).to receive(:articles).and_return article # stubbing
  expect(dbl.articles).to eql(article) # invoking the stubbed method
end
```

You can try to remove `get :index` line from that example, and you will see that the code is still passing.

You could write the example without stubbing just as well:

```
let(:article) { create :article }

it 'assigns @articles' do
  get :index
  expect(assigns(:articles)).to contain_exactly(article)
end
```

If you are started programming with Rails and RSpec, I would recommend using real objects whenever you can. The documentation for rspec-rails has a lot good examples: http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs
If you want to learn more about mocking and stubbing the RSpec documentation is a pretty good place for that too.

Answer (score 1):

```
  # This is a stub
  fake_article = allow(article).to receive(:compute_price).and_return(200)

  # This too
  another_fake_article = double(compute_price: 200)

  # This is a mock
  expect(article).to receive(:where).with(status: :closed)
```

The last one will fail if your article does not call the `where` method with the `{ status: :closed }` parameter hash. Hope that helps.